# MyEclipse 8.6 won't create Spring DAOs using Hibernate reverse engineering

Tags: hibernate, spring, reverse-engineering, myeclipse

I have a project that I got from someone else. I don't know how exactly they configured it. All I know is that MyEclipse thinks the project has Spring and Hibernate capabilities but not Hibernate 3, which is required for reverse engineering to output Spring DAOs. Therefore the option to create Spring DAOs is grayed out, when in reality the project does use Hibernate 3.

**Is there some way to trick or force MyEclipse into reverse engineering the tables and creating Spring DAOs, or just to convince it that it is indeed using Hibernate 3, which would allow normal reverse engineering?** I want to avoid remaking the project.

If there is some other convenient way to reverse engineer them and bring them into the project, I would be perfectly happy with that, as long as it ouput something that MyEclipse could understand. I am new to this area, so I really only know how to use MyEclipse for the reverse engineering at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the person who provided the project, and he says the best method is to simply create a new project and copy all the code files into it (not the MyEclipse files), then add all the desired capabilities. He has been using MyEclipse for a long time and does not know of any way to remove capabilities once they are added.